# Reusing query expression with related DbSets

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

Is it possible to re-use query expression across DbSets?
I have a nearly identical method in two service classes.  The only difference is the DbSet they operate on.  How can I make this generic so I do not have to recreate the query logic for every other service that follows this pattern.

```cs
public abstract class JobWithHistoryBase : JobBase, IHistoryWith
{/* common properties and methods defined */}

public class MeterInstallJob : JobWithHistoryBase 
{/* not relevant */}

public class MeterRepairJob : JobWithHistoryBase 
{/* not relevant */}

public class MeterInstallService
{ 
    /* context plumbing */
    public async Task<List<JobHistoryDto>> GetHistoryForWorkflow()
    {
        using var context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
        var result = await context.MeterInstallJob /* <-- */
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(x => x.WorkflowId == workflowId)
            .Select(x => new JobHistoryDto()
            {
                WorkflowId = x.WorkflowId,
                ActivityLabel = x.Activity.Label,
                ActivityByPersonUserName = x.ActivityByPerson.Username,
                ActivityStartDate = x.ActivityStartDate,
                Comment = x.Comment
            })
            .ToListAsync();
    }
}
public class MeterRepairService
{ 
    /* context plumbing */
    public async Task<List<JobHistoryDto>> GetHistoryForWorkflow()
    {
        using var context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
        var result = await context.MeterRepairJob /* <-- */
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(x => x.WorkflowId == workflowId)
            .Select(x => new JobHistoryDto()
            {
                WorkflowId = x.WorkflowId,
                ActivityLabel = x.Activity.Label,
                ActivityByPersonUserName = x.ActivityByPerson.Username,
                ActivityStartDate = x.ActivityStartDate,
                Comment = x.Comment
            })
            .ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

I'm hoping for something like this:

```cs
public static async Task<List<JobHistoryDto>> GetHistoryForDbSet(DbSet<JobWithHistoryBase> dbset, int workflowId)
{
    using var context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
    var result = await dbset /* <-- */
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Where(x => x.WorkflowId == workflowId)
        .Select(x => new JobHistoryDto()
        {
            WorkflowId = x.WorkflowId,
            ActivityLabel = x.Activity.Label,
            ActivityByPersonUserName = x.ActivityByPerson.Username,
            ActivityStartDate = x.ActivityStartDate,
            Comment = x.Comment
        })
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Using an `IQueryable` for the input and output would also solve this problem as the context and execution of the query can be handled in the service class instead. Eventually, I'd want to implement these in a base service class that these services are built on.

Comment: Sounds like standard generic method receiving `IQueryable<T>` with generic constraint `where T :  JobWithHistoryBase`. Inside the body, replace `context.MeterInstallJob` with `context.Set<T>()` and you are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
public static async Task<List<JobHistoryDto>> GetHistoryForWorkflow<T>(int workflowId) 
    where T: JobWithHistoryBase
{
    using var context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
    var result = await context.Set<T>()
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Where(x => x.WorkflowId == workflowId)
        .Select(x => new JobHistoryDto()
        {
            WorkflowId = x.WorkflowId,
            ActivityLabel = x.Activity.Label,
            ActivityByPersonUserName = x.ActivityByPerson.Username,
            ActivityStartDate = x.ActivityStartDate,
            Comment = x.Comment
        })
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

And call like this:

```
var x = await GetHistoryForWorkflow<MeterRepairJob>(10);
```

I don't have a compiler to check right not, but please let me know if you have any problem with this.